# How to make millions of parallel http requests from nodejs app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, npm

I have to make a million http calls from my nodejs app.

Apart from doing it using async lib, callbacks is there any other way to call these many requests in parallel to process it much faster?

Kindly suggest me on the same

Comment: Web worker, child process, async...

Answer (score 5):

As the title of your question seems to ask, it's a bit of a folly to actually make millions of parallel requests.  Having that many requests in flight at the same time will not help you get the job done any quicker and it will likely exhaust many system resources (memory, sockets, bandwidth, etc...).

Instead, if the goal is to just process millions of requests as fast as possible, then you want to do the following:

1. Start up enough parallel node.js processes so that you are using all the CPU you have available for processing the request responses.  If you have 8 cores in each server involved in the process, then start up 8 node.js processes per server.
2. Install as much networking bandwidth capability as possible (high throughput connection, multiple network cards, etc...) so you can do the networking as fast as possible.
3. Use asynchronous I/O processing for all I/O so you are using the system resources as efficiently as possible.  Be careful about disk I/O because async disk I/O in node.js actually uses a limited thread pool internal to the node implementation so you can't have an indefinite number of async disk I/O requests actually in flight at the same time.  You won't get an error if you try to do this (the excess requests will just be queued), but it won't help you with performance either.  Networking in node.js is truly async so it doesn't have this issue.
4. Open only as many simultaneous requests per node.js process as actually benefit you.  How many this is (likely somewhere between 2 and 20) depends upon how much of the total time to process a request is networking vs. CPU and how slow the responses are.  If all the requests are going to the same remote server, then saturating it with requests likely won't help you either because you're already asking it to do as much as it can do.
5. Create a coordination mechanism among your multiple node.js processes to feed each one work and possibly collect results (something like a work queue is often used).
6. Test like crazy and discover where your bottlenecks are and investigate how to tune or change code to reduce the bottlenecks.
7. If your requests are all to the same remote server then you will have to figure out how it behaves with multiple requests.  A larger server farm will probably not behave much differently if you fire 10 requests at it at once vs. 100 requests at once.  But, a single smaller remote server might actually behave worse if you fire 100 requests at it at once.  If your requests are all to different hosts, then you don't have this issue at all.  If your requests are to a mixture of different hosts and same hosts, then it may pay to spread them around to different hosts so that you aren't making 100 at once of the same host.

The basic ideas behind this are:

1. You want to maximize your use of the CPU so each CPU is always doing as much as it can.
2. Since your node.js code is single threaded, you need one node.js process per core in order to maximize your use of the CPU cycles available.  Adding additional node.js processes beyond the number of cores will just incur unnecessary OS context switching costs and probably not help performance.
3. You only need enough parallel requests in flight at the same time to keep the CPU fed with work.  Having lots of excess requests in flight beyond what is needed to feed the CPU just increases memory usage beyond what is helpful.  If you have enough memory to hold the excess requests, it isn't harmful to have more, but it isn't helpful either.  So, ideally you'd set things to have a few more requests in flight at a time than are needed to keep the CPU busy.